# Connecting via SPSite and accessing/Reading a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell

So far I am unable to access my list using a SharePoint site URL.

When I use `get-spweb` I get

> "Cannot find an spweb object with Id or Url"

but I can easily type in the URL(https://test.contoso.com/visitors/siteName) in IE and see the site.

So therefore I can't do `$list = $web.Lists` to iterate through lists.

Now I can do `get-spsite` with the URL but then I cannot do anything at that point, I cannot use the `$web.Lists` nor can I use `$site.title`.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you running this PowerShell from one of the SharePoint web front end servers or from a remote computer?

Comment: I am running it from the web front end server it is hosted on. @Thriggle

Comment: Are you able to get the site (`$site = get-spsite http:...`) and then access `$site.RootWeb.lists`?

Comment: @Thriggle I haven't tried that method yet, though I will. I have left the office for the day but I will follow up first thing tomorrow. Thanks for responding so fast by the way!

Comment: No problem! My only theory at the moment is that `https://test.contoso.com/visitors/siteName` is the path to some object within a subsite (such as a folder or library) instead of the path to a specific SPWeb, which is why it's complaining that it can't find a web at that URL. If you can get the containing site collection, you should be able to drill down to the desired subsite through `$site.RootWeb`, `$site.OpenWeb()`, or `$site.AllWebs`

Comment: I think I may have made some progress using the $site.RootWeb.Lists then foreach$list in $lists but now I get "The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>". @Thriggle

Comment: Found the issue. It was a new content database and they neglected to add the proper permissions. Womp Womp. Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Glad you solved it! Feel free to post that as a self-answer when you have the time; self-answers are not only acceptable but encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content database the site was hosted on did not have correct permissions for the account trying to run the powershell.

This will cause the subsite to not properly show up when looking through all sites as well as it will cause an error if you try to use get-spweb.

Once the permissions were corrected the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should be aware of the difference between `Get-SPWeb` and `Get-SPSite`

- [`Get-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807.aspx) : is used to return all site / subsites. for more details check [Get-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807.aspx)
- [`Get-SPSite`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx): is used to return a site collection. for more details check [Get-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx)

So if the above link is a subsite, you should use `Get-SPWeb`, to iterate through list within a **subsite** , try to run the following script

- Open SharePoint Managment PowerShell as administrator
- Run the following code

**Code**

```
 $spweb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://epm/workflow
 foreach($list in $spweb.Lists)
        {
          write-host $list.Title
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

If you need to iterate over all lists within a specific site URL in a site collection via `Get-SPSite` , you can use the following script

```
 $spsite = Get-SPSite http://rootsiteURL

foreach($spweb in $spsite.Allwebs)
        {
if ($spweb.URL -eq "http://fullsiteURL")

{
   foreach($list in $spweb.Lists)
        {
write-host $list.Title
}
}
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note :** If you tried to use `Get-SPSite` to access a **subsite directly** you will get the following error :

[image]

Comment: This still doesn't produce the site I am trying to connect to. It shows a lot of subsites but not the one I am looking for.

Comment: Dear @TheInexperiencedGamer I provide you more details with snapshot  and different scenarios, only what you need to decide if your site is subsite use the first example , else use the second example ,  but I am sure the provided script should work as I mentioned above at output section ,so  are you tried the second example, also please share your current code ! and  Please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification !!

Comment: I have tried it both ways, they do list a bunch of subsites but my subsite isn't listed despite doing an like statement to just hit the keyword when searching through the results sadly. I am starting to wonder if the DB this subsite is hosted on is set up correctly permission wise.

Comment: are you sure the above link is subsite ?! maybe you added a managed path with Wildcard inclusion as visitors and the above Url is a site collection, not subsite ?  so in this case get-spweb will not be worked with you so try to run this code $spsite = Get-SPSite https://test.contoso.com/visitors/siteName

foreach($spweb in $spsite.Allwebs)
        {
if ($spweb.URL -eq "https://test.contoso.com/visitors/siteName")

{
   foreach($list in $spweb.Lists)
        {
write-host $list.Title
}
}
}

Comment: It ended up being the new content database didn't have its permissions set up correctly. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Great Job , and you are welcome :)